# Dynamically select columns with joins in runtime Entity framework core

Tags: c#, sql, linq, dynamic, entity-framework-core

I have this search method with a lot of includes:

```
public IQueryable<Order> Search(Expression<Func<Order, bool>> predicate)
{
    IQueryable<Order> query = DbContext.Orders.AsQueryable()
           .Include(x => x.Client)
           .Include(x => x.Status)
           ......

    if (!PredicateEmpty.Equals(predicate.Body.ToString(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        query = query.Where(predicate);
    }

    return query;
}
```

when we go to the database we get on all of data from the tables and now the client want a dynamic column grid, for that we want to optimize this search by doing a dynamic select based of the user select columns and for that select maybe have a join to another table  or not.

Can someone tell me how can do this or or something I can read to guide me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well with custom Select, you should forgot about includes. Start from projecting single column.

Comment: I starts with that, and for now this works, thanks!